# How to eliminate empty leaf elements from an XML file without holding the whole XML in memory?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, sax, jdom, dom4j

We need to eliminate elements from an XML file, elements that satisfy one of the following conditions:
C1. They are leaf elements (not having other elements as children) and their trimmed text (concatenated from the non-element child nodes) is empty (only whitespace).
-or-
C2. They have only children respecting C1 or C2. In other words,
C2. They do not have any child element that does not respect C1 or C2.

So it is a recursive cleanup algorithm. The problem with the DOM approach is that it takes a multiple of the XML size to store the tree in memory. We are looking at alternatives for a constant-memory approach even if we need multiple read-write cycles with the disk, e.g. writing multiple XML files until the desired XML is produced.

We have a dom4j implementation but it takes about 5 times memory as the XML size (it keeps all the tree in memory apparently, although no changes are actually operated in the particular test - no element eliminated in the particular test case).

We are considering just doing C1 on the full XML in one iteration (if it can be done in a way to consume less memory, e.g. matching the whitespace leaves with XPath and taking them out without loading the whole structure in memory - is there a way to uniquely identify such elements? Is XPath always uniquely identifying the nodes?), output to a file, and do it iteratively until no leaves are matched and the XML is cleaned up then.

A transformation in one step or multiple steps, involving JVM processing with Java or XSLT or anything else, that takes a random XML (multiple XML schemas involved), and outputs a cleanup up XML (as a file or output/input stream).

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky because it involves lookahead. Consider

```
<a>
  <b/>
  <c/>
  <d/>
  <z>23</z>
</a>
```

You don't know whether to eliminate the `<a>` element until you have seen the `<z/>` element. So this certainly isn't a pure streamable transformation.

What you could to in a single pass is to build a list of all the elements that are to be eliminated.

It would be useful to know whether you expect to eliminate very many or very few elements; in the first case, a first pass should collect references to the elements that are to be retained, in the second case, it should collect references to those that are to be dropped.

I think that another way of expressing your requirement is: eliminate any element that is not the ancestor of at least one non-whitespace text node.

It's easy enough in a streamable XSLT 3.0 transformation to gather the paths of all ancestors of non-whitespace text nodes:

```
//text()[normalize-space()] ! ancestor::* ! path(.)
```

The only problem is that without any volumetrics I don't know whether this list is impossibly large. You can eliminate duplicates as you go by putting this in a map expression:

```
map:merge(//text()[normalize-space()] ! ancestor::* ! path(.) ! map{.:1},
            map{'duplicates':'use-first'})
```

Having built this list, it's then easy enough to do a streaming transformation that eliminates elements not on the list:

```
<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="*[not(map:contains($retained-path, path(.))]"/>
```

As I say, the problem is that the list of retained nodes could get very large.

Another approach is to try and construct a list of paths of elements to be dropped. An algorithm for this might be: when you encounter an element start tag, add the element to the list of candidates for elimination; when you encounter a non-whitespace text node, remove all its ancestors from the list. The problem is that as expressed here, it requires a mutable data structure for the list. This makes it a candidate for XSLT 3.0 accumulators:

```
<xsl:accumulator name="dropped-elements" as="map(xs:string, xs:integer)">
 <xsl:accumulator-rule match="*" select="map:merge($value, map{path(.), 1}"/>
 <xsl:accumulator-rule match="text()[normalize-space()]
    select="map:remove($value, ancestor::*!path(.))"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

and then at the end of processing `map:keys(accumulator-after('dropped-elements'))` gives you the paths of elements to be dropped.

All untested: I hope this gives you some ideas.